# How to have an output based on an uploaded file with Flask?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, flask, import

I would like to have a Flask app who let the user put a csv file and it return an output like `head()` or another (for now)

Here's my `app.py` :

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import os
import pandas as pd

ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = {'csv', 'txt', 'pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'}
UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'uploads/'
    

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and filename.rsplit('.',1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def upload_file(filename=None,column=None, data=None):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash("No file part")
            return redirect(request.url)

        file = request.files['file']

        if file.filename == '':
            flash("No selected file")
            return redirect(request.url)

        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file_path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
            file.save(file_path)
            df = pd.read_csv(file_path, delimiter = ';')
            column = list(df)
            data = [list(df[d]) for d in column]

    return render_template('index.html', filename=filename, data=data, column=column)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Here's my `index.html` file :

```
<!doctype <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Upload File</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css" />
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    {% if data %}
    <p>Data Found</p>
    {% endif %}
    <h1>Upload new File</h1>
    <form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
      <input type=file name=file>
      <input type=submit value=Upload>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's how it looklike when I import a csv file :

[input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNLTo.png)

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTp6Z.png)

My question is : Instead of having the "data found !", how can I have like a output based on the csv file just imported, like `head()`, or `data['variable'].value_counts()` for example.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can render Pandas table in HTML once the file is uploaded.

Flask Code:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import os
import pandas as pd

ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = {'csv', 'txt', 'pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'}
UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'uploads/'
    

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and filename.rsplit('.',1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def upload_file(filename=None,column=None, data=None):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        render_template('index.html')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash("No file part")
            return redirect(request.url)

        file = request.files['file']

        if file.filename == '':
            flash("No selected file")
            return redirect(request.url)

        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file_path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
            file.save(file_path)
            df = pd.read_csv(file_path, delimiter = ';')
            column = list(df)
            data = [list(df[d]) for d in column]
            df_head = df.head()

            return render_template('index.html', data=data, tables=[df_head.to_html(classes='data')], titles=df.columns.values)

    return render_template('index.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

HTML Code:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Upload File</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css" />
        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        {% if data %}
        {% for table in tables %}
            {{titles[loop.index]}}
            {{ table|safe }}
        {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
        <h1>Upload new File</h1>
        <form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
          <input type=file name=file>
          <input type=submit value=Upload>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'df' referenced before assignment` ? I don't understant this error because `df` is referenced before.

Comment: `df` variable does not exist yet, if method is `GET`, add separate `return render_template('index.html')` call for `GET` requests.

Comment: I have updated the code based on @vremes suggestion.

Comment: `TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.` This time I do not understand this error.

Comment: Keep in mind that `flash` relies on Flask `app.secret_key`, which is undefined, `flash` calls will result to Internal Server Error.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that earlier when I tried to upload nothing. But apparently `flask.ext.session` is deprecated so...

Comment: *  `flash.ext` :)